# Is there a way in Visual Stuio's compilation settings to combine other referenced DLLs into the built assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies, ilmerge, net-reactor

I have an EXE that I want to distribute, but I don't want to ship all the associated DLLs with it (sort of).

Currently I package them all together using .NET Reactor.

I tried ILMerge a while back to achieve the same, but when I tried it I ran into trouble - .NET Reactor has never, ever failed me.

Is there a way to achieve this in the compilation settings in Visual Studio?

Would it mean wrapping up a call to ILMerge in the build actions? If so, can anyone give me some pointers to the right way to set this up? I am willing to give ILMerge a second chance, it's been two years..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many](http://blogs.msdn.com/jomo_fisher/archive/2006/03/05/544144.aspx), [many](http://code.google.com/p/ilmerge-tasks/wiki/HowToUse), [many](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/10/06/2326.aspx) places on the web the explain how to use ILMerge with MSBuild. It not a compilation setting but its close enough.